# Is it possible to replace page arguments with new ones in a view exposed filter?

Tags: views, 8

I'm creating a views filter with the exposed form.

[image: The exposed filter form with countries and regions]

After its submitting a new page is loaded with arguments like these (I use the Acquia Dev desktop)

```
http://pal.dd:8083/en/cities?country_id=2&region_id=4
```

I want to make the string shorter, for example, like this

```
http://pal.dd:8083/en/cities?geo=2_4
```

And in the query() method transcribe this argument and get country and region value from it.

I'm wondering, is it possible to do it inside the view filter class?

I tried to manipulate with the values of the exposed form in the submitExposed function, but I didn't manage to achieve the positive result.

Has anybody run into it?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the default `Filter identifier` for each Exposed Filter in its settings. The Description:

> **Filter identifier**
>   _
>   This will appear in the URL after the ? to identify this filter. Cannot be blank. Only letters, digits and the dot ("."), hyphen ("-"), underscore ("_"), and tilde ("~") characters are allowed.

In your case you can chage the first one to `geo` and the other to `_`. That way you get the output:

`cities?geo=2&_=4`

although you'd probably name the second one to something more meaningful, like `region`:

`cities?geo=2&region=4`

For full control use the module [Query Parameters To URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/query_parameters_to_url) ([Drupal 8 version Needs work](https://www.drupal.org/project/contrib_tracker/issues/2835060)).

Comment: Thanks.
Can I drop using country and region filters in the query and use only the geo filter, which will contain country_id value and region_id value ?
And in what method can I calculate and set the value of the geo filter?